# how to add cookie in the header using retrofit2?

Tags: android, web-services, retrofit2

i need to add cookie with session id and session name in the header of webservice.

```
@POST(ApiUrl.AUTH_TOKEN_VERIFICATION)
Call<LogoutResponse> authTokenVerification(@Body Logout logout);
```

This is my current implementation. How to append header tag with cookie. do i need to create a cookie object or how to achieve this?

Comment: are you using OkHttp ? that way it's more simple to do so

Answer (score 0):

You can send cookie in HEADER in Retrofit as given below :

```
@POST(ApiUrl.AUTH_TOKEN_VERIFICATION)
Call<LogoutResponse> authTokenVerification(@Body Logout logout, @Header("Cookie") String sessionIdAndName);
```

Comment: Sudheesh eta, sessionIdAndToken nta format enthanu?

Comment: Using "&" or "=" in between sessionid and session name

Comment: its a string. eg: sessionIdAndName = 534545464656abcd

Comment: this will be helpful for you https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-manage-request-headers-in-okhttp-interceptor

Comment: you can't send two cookies in a single header, that's why I combined your token and name into one.

Comment: did you get it ?

Comment: yeah got it. cookie string will look like "sessionid=sessionname". "=" is my requirement.